# Dynamic pulling Excel workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am responsible for running weekly reports for work. I am using a personal VBA module to build out the code. The workbooks will all be using the same naming convention, the only difference will be the dates at the end of the workbook. For example: I want to pull from workbook A, named "workbook A 10.28.19.xlsx", into workbook B, named "workbook B 11.4.19.xlsx". How can i make it so that i don't have to manually change the workbook name in the code every week?

Just started learning VBA, and I've considered using wildcard characters for string references but I think the nature of the naming conventions makes it a bit harder.

This is what I have so far:

```
    Workbooks("workbook A 
    10.28.19.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("AD:AE").Copy _
    Workbooks("workbook B 
    11.4.19.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("AD:AE")
    End Sub
```

The code works fine, it is just a matter of making it dynamic, if possible

EDIT: Thank you for the comments so far. Some clarifications I will add here: "workbook A/B" that i used in the example are fixed names, and the only thing that will change is the date. The report will always use the Monday dates because I need to look at WoW totals, so it falling on a holiday does not matter. Once 2020 rolls around, the dates will indeed be changed to xx.xx.20.

Comment: Is the date always the Monday of this week and the Monday of the last? What if Monday is a holiday?

Comment: What happens after New year?

Comment: ...basically you need to explain what the rules are for which files you'd look for.

Comment: Also the names are not following a pattern that we can know yet. It starts with `a` the next week is `b`, what happens on week three? `b` and `c`?

Comment: @Andreas I assume `A` and `B` are fixed names, and only the date changes... but we still very much need OP to clarify the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you need.

It will first look if today is monday, then use todays date as workbook A and B as last weeks monday.
If it's not monday then it will find previous monday as A, and one week back find the previous monday as B.

```
If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 1 Then
    wkbA = Format(Date, "MM.D.YY") & ".xlsx"
    wkbB = Format(Date - Weekday(Date - 1, vbMonday), "MM.D.YY") & ".xlsx"
Else
    wkbA = Format(Date - Weekday(Date - 1, vbMonday), "MM.D.YY") & ".xlsx"
    wkbB = Format(Date - Weekday(Date - 7, vbMonday), "MM.D.YY") & ".xlsx"
End If
```